# Error creating bean with name 'clienteController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clienteService';

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to start my Spring Boot application but the error below is returning me:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clienteController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clienteService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clienteService' defined in file [C:\Users\RenanFreitasDevenz\Documents\api-simulacao\target\classes\com\simulacao\api\services\ClienteService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clienteRepository' defined in com.simulacao.api.repository.ClienteRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property buscarClientePorId found for type Cliente!
```

Class ClienteRepository:

```
package com.simulacao.api.repository;

import com.simulacao.api.documents.Cliente;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends MongoRepository<Cliente, String> {

    Cliente buscarClientePorId(String id);
    Cliente buscarClientePorNome(String nome);
    Optional<Cliente> buscarClientePorCpf(String cpf);
}
```

Class ClienteService:

```
package com.simulacao.api.services;

import com.simulacao.api.repository.ClienteRepository;
import com.simulacao.api.documents.Cliente;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Component
public class ClienteService {

    @Autowired
    private final ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    public ClienteService(ClienteRepository clienteRepository) {

        this.clienteRepository = clienteRepository;
    }

    public List<Cliente> listarTodos() {

        return this.clienteRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Cliente listarPorId(String id) {

        return clienteRepository.buscarClientePorId(id);
    }

    public Cliente listarPorNome(String nome) {

        return clienteRepository.buscarClientePorNome(nome);
    }

    public Cliente salvar(Cliente cliente) {

        return this.clienteRepository.save(cliente);
    }

    public Cliente atualizar(Cliente cliente) {

        return this.clienteRepository.save(cliente);
    }

    public Optional<Cliente> verificarCliente(String cpf) {

        return this.clienteRepository.buscarClientePorCpf(cpf);
    }

    public void remover(String id) {

        clienteRepository.deleteById(id);

    }
}
```

Class ClienteController:

```
package com.simulacao.api.controller;

import com.simulacao.api.documents.Cliente;
import com.simulacao.api.documents.Transacao;
import com.simulacao.api.repository.ClienteRepository;
import com.simulacao.api.services.ClienteService;
import com.simulacao.api.services.ContaService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/clientes")
@Api(value = "API Rest Clientes")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class ClienteController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteService clienteService;

    @Autowired
    private ContaService contaService;

    @Autowired
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    @GetMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retorna uma lista de clientes")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Cliente>> listarTodos() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.clienteService.listarTodos());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{cpf}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retorna os dados de um cliente")
    public ResponseEntity<Cliente> dadosCliente(@PathVariable String cpf) {
        Optional<Cliente> cliente = clienteRepository.buscarClientePorCpf(cpf);

        return cliente.map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "Salva um cliente")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<Cliente> cadastrar(@Valid @RequestBody Cliente cliente) {

        if (!clienteRepository.existsById(cliente.getCpf())) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.clienteService.salvar(cliente));
    }

    @PutMapping("depositar/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Realiza um deposito na conta")
    public ResponseEntity<?> depositar(@PathVariable double valor, @PathVariable String id){

        this.contaService.depositar(valor);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping(path = "sacar/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Realiza um saque na conta")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sacar(@PathVariable double valor, @PathVariable String id) throws Exception {
        if (valor <= 0) {
            throw new Exception("valor incorreto");
        }
        this.contaService.sacar(valor);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // Histórico de transações
    @GetMapping(path = "extratoConta/{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Retorna uma lista de movimentações")
    public ResponseEntity<?> extratoConta(@PathVariable String id){
        List<Transacao> transacoes = contaService.extratoConta(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(transacoes,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{clienteId}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Remove um cliente")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deletar(@PathVariable String clienteId) {
        clienteService.remover(clienteId);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

Class Cliente:

```
package com.simulacao.api.documents;

import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.br.CPF;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Document
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Nome não pode ser vazio")
    private String nome;

    @Indexed(unique=true)
    @CPF
    private String cpf;

    private Conta conta;

    private boolean ativo;
}
```

What I tried to do but didn't fix:
1 - Annotate the main class with @ComponentScan ("com.simulacao.api")

2 - Note the class of service with @Service.

If you need me to post any more code snippets, let me know.

What can be done?

Comment: Your question has a lot of code. Could you, please, narrow it down to the specific problem and make it clear where you struggle? also, please format your code when posting, in that case, you will attract more readers.

Comment: I posted the code flow where the problem was pointed out, according to the exception that I reported.

Comment: Isn't this part of exception `No property buscarClientePorId found for type Cliente!` helpful for you?

Comment: It did not solve the problem.

Comment: What is *it*? how did you try to solve it? do you have that field as a property mapped accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your code that in your repository, you have method `Cliente buscarClientePorId(String id);` and similar methods.

You are using Query Methods and it must have something like `findByFollowedByPropertyOfYourEntity`.

According to the Spring Data Repository docs,

> Spring Data JPA does a property check and traverses nested properties

Change your method according to this [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) and it should work.

For instance, change your method inside the repository to

```
@Repository
public interface ClienteRepository extends MongoRepository<Cliente, 
String> {
    Cliente findById(String id);
}
```

Comment: I made the adjustment but the problem remains.
`Optional<Cliente> findById(String id);`

Comment: Same error? You were getting error because the property didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I had to adapt the queries of the repository to:

```
findByParametro ...
```

Ex:

```
findBy "Property name"
```